# Making animation of flood fill in vb return object is currently used elsewhere using thread.sleep

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, graphics, thread-sleep

I tried making animated flood fill (scanline algorithm) using sleep in vb. So it will show the order of pixels being colored. It will work for a little bit but then it will return object is currently used elsewhere

This is my code

```
Sub AnimatedRFRecursive(ByVal P As Point, ByVal C0 As Color, ByVal C1 As Color)

    Dim i, xL, xR As Integer
    Dim a As Point
    i = P.X
    While (i >= 0 AndAlso BMP.GetPixel(i, P.Y) = C0)
        Thread.Sleep(10)
        BMP.SetPixel(i, P.Y, C1)
        PictureBox1.Invoke(New Action(Sub() PictureBox1.Image = BMP))
        i -= 1
    End While
    xL = i + 1
    i = P.X + 1
    While (i < 500 AndAlso BMP.GetPixel(i, P.Y) = C0)
        Thread.Sleep(10)
        BMP.SetPixel(i, P.Y, C1)
        PictureBox1.Invoke(New Action(Sub() PictureBox1.Image = BMP))
    End While
    xR = i - 1
    For i = xL To xR
        If (P.Y < 349 AndAlso BMP.GetPixel(i, P.Y + 1) = C0) Then
            a.X = i
            a.Y = P.Y + 1

            AnimatedRFRecursive(a, C0, C1)
        End If
        If (P.Y > 0 AndAlso BMP.GetPixel(i, P.Y - 1) = C0) Then
            a.X = i
            a.Y = P.Y - 1
            AnimatedRFRecursive(a, C0, C1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This is how I call it

```
Dim thr As New Threading.Thread(Sub() AnimatedRFRecursive(point, C, Color))
thr.Start()
```

Please tell me where did I do wrong or if you have any other method that works also do. Thank you

Comment: Do you get the error if you comment out the Picture1.Invoke lines?

Comment: I didn't. But the picture fill is not shown

Comment: You won't have much use for this code.  It fails because Bitmap can be accessed by only one thread at a time.  The second thread that accesses it is the UI thread, happens when the PictureBox content needs to be repainted.  Fairly random but pretty likely to happen.  You'd normally use the *lock* keyword to prevent that from happening but you can't insert that statement in the code of PictureBox.  You'd have to make your own.  Just don't use a thread, it doesn't help at all.  Use a timer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple threads that need to access the same object (BMP).  This will require that you synchronize access to the BMP object.

Please note that your original code has two magic numbers (500 and 349) that I assumed correspond to the bitmap's width and height.  Change the usage of the  variables in the code below if this assumption if incorrect.

```
Private BMP As Bitmap
Private BMPKey As New Object
Private Sub UpdatePictureBox()
    PictureBox1.Invoke(Sub()
                                SyncLock BMPKey
                                    Dim oldBM As Image = PictureBox1.Image
                                    PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(BMP)
                                    If oldBM IsNot Nothing Then oldBM.Dispose()
                                End SyncLock

                                End Sub)

End Sub

Private Function GetBMPPixel(x As Int32, y As Int32) As Color
    SyncLock BMPKey
        Return BMP.GetPixel(x, y)
    End SyncLock
End Function

Private Sub SetBMPPixel(x As Int32, y As Int32, c As Color)
    SyncLock BMPKey
        BMP.SetPixel(x, y, c)
    End SyncLock
End Sub

Sub AnimatedRFRecursive(ByVal P As Point, ByVal C0 As Color, ByVal C1 As Color)

     Dim i, xL, xR As Integer
     Dim a As Point
     i = P.X
     Dim width As Int32
     Dim height As Int32
     SyncLock BMPKey
        width = BMP.Width       ' original code magic number of 500 
        height = BMP.Height ' original code magic number of 349  
     End SyncLock
     While (i >= 0 AndAlso GetBMPPixel(i, P.Y).ToArgb = C0.ToArgb)
          Thread.Sleep(10)
          SetBMPPixel(i, P.Y, C1)
          UpdatePictureBox()
          i -= 1
     End While
     xL = i + 1
     i = P.X + 1
     While (i < width - 1 AndAlso GetBMPPixel(i, P.Y).ToArgb = C0.ToArgb)
          Thread.Sleep(10)
          SetBMPPixel(i, P.Y, C1)
          UpdatePictureBox()
     End While
     xR = i - 1
     For i = xL To xR
          If (P.Y < height - 1 AndAlso GetBMPPixel(i, P.Y + 1).ToArgb = C0.ToArgb) Then
                a.X = i
                a.Y = P.Y + 1

                AnimatedRFRecursive(a, C0, C1)
          End If
          If (P.Y > 0 AndAlso GetBMPPixel(i, P.Y - 1).ToArgb = C0.ToArgb) Then
                a.X = i
                a.Y = P.Y - 1
                AnimatedRFRecursive(a, C0, C1)
          End If
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It works for  awhile but after that it returns this "Bitmap region is already locked"

Comment: Weirdly it can jump from the second while to the for loop

Comment: @NatJ - I made a small change to the code.  Give that a try.  Also, do you start multiple threads that call `AnimatedRFRecursive`?  If so, the logic will need to implement locks to prevent concurrent access.

Comment: @NatJ,  I had some time, so I rewrote your code to include the needed locks.  Hopefully this solves your issue.

Comment: I am not really sure about that. Thank you I shall try the code now.

Comment: It works. Thank you. But when I when I click button to clear the screen I will get error **parameter is not valid** in function `GetBMPPixel`. And also if I abruptly close the the form I will get **cannot access a disposed object** error in `UpdatePictureBox`

Comment: "What is synclock, edit, offset and, beep? "  The code in the button1_click was just for me to test.  No need to worry about that stuff.  `SyncLock` is a way of blocking code execution until a shared resource is free for manipulation; you can lookup thee details.  As far as the error on button clicks that you are receiving, I only added a minimal of value error checking;  you likely need to add a few checks to your code.  The VS Debugger will provide your the hints to track down the offending lines.